# Rail 6 Webpack import JS third party library Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I want to using [ToastifyJS](https://github.com/apvarun/toastify-js/) as JS Library for toast in my Rails app. Since Rails 6 using Webpack as default so I did google for a while and end up no where.

Here is what I did:

Install Rails 6:

```
rails _6.0.0.rc1_ new myapp -d mysql
```

Install JS library toastify-js:

```
yarn add toastify-js
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import "toastify-js/src/toastify";
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import Toastify from 'toastify-js'

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  Toastify({
    text: "This is a toast",
    duration: 3000,
    destination: "https://github.com/apvarun/toastify-js",
    newWindow: true,
    close: true,
    gravity: "top", // `top` or `bottom`
    position: 'left', // `left`, `center` or `right`
    backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
    stopOnFocus: true // Prevents dismissing of toast on hover
  }).showToast();
})
```

Work as expected. However what I want is a little different. As a toast/notification, you may code somethings like this:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if flash.any? %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        Toastify({
          text: "<%= value %>",
          backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)"        
        }).showToast();
      <% end%>
    })
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I got this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Toastify is not defined` although I did `import Toastify from 'toastify-js'` in `application.js`?

There is one more things, to make code structure more clean, I write all js about toast in one file:

app/javascript/packs/toast.js

```
import Toastify from 'toastify-js'

const toastNotice = Toastify({
  text: "This is a toast",
  backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
});

const toastAlert = Toastify({
  text: "This is a toast",
  backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #fcb045, #fd1d1d)",
});
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import './toast.js'
```

app/views/shared/_flash.html.erb

```
<% if flash.any? %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      toast<%= key.capitalize %>.options.text = "<%= value%>";
      toast<%= key.capitalize %>.showToast();
    <% end%>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

But again, I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: toastAlert is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question at my community so I will sum up answer here. This is not an issue from Rails or Rails 6. The problem is about **scope**. We need to expose our library to global scope.

We can either expose manually through window object or use <strike>Webpack `ProvidePlugin`.</strike>

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Toastify: 'toastify-js/src/toastify'
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

However, using `ProvidePlugin` doesn't expose library to global scope. It's only available in place where we using Webpack to compile to libraries, which means inside `app/packs/application.js`. So when we write our script in view template, those code doesn't compiled by Webpack, so it will be not defined.

So we can either:

1. Expose using window object: `window.myModule = myModule`
2. Using Webpack `expose-loader` (actually what it does is to expose using window object)

But however we shouldn't write script in global scope or dynamically insert script tag. In this specific case, to render toast. We should:

1. Output html `data-` attributes when we have toast.
2. In `app/packs/application.js` import js library
3. Using `getElementByClass` ... then get data about toasts
4. Execute library code on those toasts

We should embed info into DOM because:

1. No need to write js in view template
2. Can `defer` script execution
3. Progressive enhancement